# Filter rows from Excel on import with Django Import-Export

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I have a new Django web-application (My first one in python) and im using Import-export in the admin section to take an excel file and upload it to my database.the upload works perfectly, but I need to add two features:

1. Is there a way to truncate all the existing data in the application database table before the upload?
2. What is the best way to filter out rows from the Excel file that don't match a condition (if column value of a row != X)

I have read the documentation and it seems like for question 2, the only option is to implement an for_delete method. I find it hard to believe this is the best way, but im brand new to python and Django.

here is my resource class

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Sale
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from import_export import resources, fields
from import_export.fields import Field
    
class SaleResource(resources.ModelResource):
    
    myColumn = fields.Field(attribute='myColumn', column_name="my_Column")
    

    class Meta:
        model = Sale

        def skip_row(self, instance, original):
            val = self.myColumn
            if val != 'myValue':
                return True



@admin.register(Sale)
class SaleAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = SaleResource
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Override `before_import()` to delete all rows.
2. Override `skip_row()` to skip the row if a condition is not met.

```py
class SaleResource(resources.ModelResource):
    myColumn = fields.Field(attribute='myColumn', column_name="my_Column")

    def before_import(self, dataset, using_transactions, dry_run, **kwargs):
        if not dry_run:
            self._meta.model.objects.delete()

    def skip_row(self, instance, original):
        # 'instance' will be an instance of Sale
        # simple compare the value set on the model instance
        return instance.myColumn != "myValue"

    class Meta:
        model = Sale
```